# how to set order by date columns in sql server

Tags: sql-server

i have a table in DB and columns like

```
01-03-2013
01-04-2013
02-03-2013
```

i want show order by like

```
01-03-2013
02-03-2013
01-04-2013
```

Please help me.

Comment: If you're storing these dates in columns with an appropriate data type (`datetime`, `datetime2`, `date` or `datetimeoffset`) they should sort naturally just by using `ORDER BY`. So what's the problem?

Comment: I believe those are column names I guess, @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: @Raj: Good catch based on question. But looking at example quoted by OP, he used difference in dates of a month - See March - April. So I doubt what you are saying is the scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably your column is not stored as one of the date datatype this is being sorted as a string based on ASCII codes

You can cast your column for sorting.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl 
ORDER BY CONVERT(datetime, userColumn, 106)
```

otherwise it's straight forward

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
ORDER BY userColumn
```

If your column contain invalid records as well, you can use default date for such records

```
SELECT * FROM tbl 
ORDER BY CONVERT(datetime, 
                 CASE ISDATE(userColumn) 
                     WHEN 1 THEN userColumn 
                     ELSE '01-01-1900' 
                 END, 106)
```

Comment: That date format is ambiguous, so if a conversion is required, `CONVERT` should be used instead of `CAST` and the correct [style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) argument supplied.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: thanks for  added information :)

Comment: The correct style here would be 106 - you're specifying what the strings look like, not what "format" you want to convert to. The strings look like `dd-mm-yyyy`, and that's style 106.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: 112 is yyyyMMdd format to which I want to convert to. 3rd parameter which is style on MSDN says `style
Is an integer expression that specifies how the CONVERT function is to translate expression`. Please correct me, If I interpreted something wrong.

Comment: No, you're converting *to* a `datetime`. Those things don't **have** a format. And the reason I said to **use** `CONVERT` is because `dd-mm-yyyy` (which is what the text currently is) is ambiguous and may be interpreted as `mm-dd-yyyy`). You're providing the style parameter to tell SQL Server how to interpret the *strings*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: aah...got your point. thanks for explaining :)